# Rails app, gmail gem, xoauth: How to grant access to a specific application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, gmail

I have a Rails application in which I would like to use the [gmail gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) to connect to a Google Apps account via XOauth and retrieve emails. I followed the [gmail_xoauth](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) instructions using the [xoauth.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough) tool to generate tokens. This gives "anonymous" access to my Google Account. I am able connect via my Rails console just fine using these credentials.

I see that the gmail_xoauth gem has options for :consumer_key and :consumer_secret. I used "anonymous" for each of these. But, if my Rails application is going to be running at, say, http://someapp.example.com, how do I grant access to this application specifically and not use "anonymous"?

Thanks.